# API Call in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

Im new to using android studio and im trying to make a API call in Android Studio using volley. I have set a button to do the API call but when clicked the application crashes. The API im using also uses a key where in its documentation says: "All requests to the API must contain the X-AUTH-TOKEN HTTP header. This header must contain your auth token." I can't really figure out why the application crashes when button is clicked.

```
   private RequestQueue queue;
   private JSONArray getText;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }
 
   private StringRequest searchNameStringRequest(String nameSearch) {
        final String API = "&X-AUTH-TOKEN=<<rfrzsucnc7eo3m5hcmq6ljdzda1lz793>>";
        final String NAME_SEARCH = "&getText=";
        final String URL_PREFIX = "https://v1.motorapi.dk";

        String url = URL_PREFIX + API + NAME_SEARCH + nameSearch;

                final StringRequest stringRequest;
                stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

                response -> {
                                 try {
                        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("list");
                        int maxItems = result.getInt("end");
                        JSONArray resultList = result.getJSONArray("item");

                  
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, 
                error -> {
               
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Motorregister dosen’t answer.”, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                });

        return stringRequest;
    }

    public void button(View view) {
   
        queue.cancelAll(this);

        StringRequest stringRequest = searchNameStringRequest(getText.toString());
        stringRequest.setTag(this);

        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

EDIT here is the crash log:

```
12/08 18:08:32: Launching 'app' on Pixel C API 29.
Install successfully finished in 1 s 791 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 5893 on device 'Pixel_C_API_29 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:19): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7291 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c147,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.example.myapplication
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd5a9e040, tid 5931
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe1113980: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1113980: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd5ace1d0)
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd5a9f850, tid 5931
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ffff6000 size 0x2000
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1113980: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd5ace1d0)
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 1576 bytes, containing 1 windows, 9 views
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 5893
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:446)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONArray.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.button(MainActivity.java:84)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5893 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please, Share your crashed log  with us.

Comment: Highly recommend using the retrofit for network communication.

Comment: We need the crash log.  But unless Volley has a feature you absolutely need, I'd avoid it.  It has a lot of boilerplate you need to write, and it has some bad implementation issues.  In particular don't download large files over it-  it keeps all of the data in a string in memory, so downloading a file of a couple hundred megs can crash you OOM

Comment: Where can i find the crash log?

Answer (score 0):

Your crash has nothing to do with Volley.  Your onclick tries to call getText.toString, but you never set the value of getText so it's a null.  You then dereference it.  You need to set the value of getText, and you probably need a null check there as well.